# getLayoutInflater bundle inssue

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle

```
itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.deal_items, parent, false);
```

Apparently I need a bundle to make the argument applicable but I don't know what that should be, any help? Thanks!

Comment: are you in a Fragment?

Comment: Yeah I am in a fragment

Comment: `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` or `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())` should do it